# Setting Refresh Token Signing Key to User's Hashed Password Using Flask_jwt_extended

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I am new to flask. I was trying to set the refresh tokens signing key as the users hashed password. I only want the refresh tokens signing key to contain the users hashed password and not the access token. I went through the flask_jwt_extended docs and came across the `encode_key_loader` method [here](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_jwt_extended/jwt_manager/#JWTManager.encode_key_loader).
However I am not sure how I change what the function returns base of the type of the token. This is what I have so far.

```
@jwt.encode_key_loader
def my_key_loader(identity):
     hash = fetch_user_password(identity)
     return "somerandomsecretkey" + hash
```

I just need to way to figure out if the type of the token being generated and then I can return the appropriate key.

Comment: you want to set the identity of the refresh token with that hash?

Comment: Not identity just to sign it with the hashed password @shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but you could accomplish this via something like (untested):

```py
@jwt.user_identity_loader
def user_identity_lookup(identity):
    return identity['user'].id

@jwt.encode_key_loader
def custom_encode_key(identity):
    secret = "<YOUR_NORMAL_JWT_ENCODE_KEY>"
    if identity['token_type'] == "access":
        return secret
    else:
        return secret + identity['user'].hashed_password

@jwt.decode_key_loader
def custom_encode_key(jwt_headers, jwt_payload):
    secret = "<YOUR_NORMAL_JWT_ENCODE_KEY>"
    if jwt_payload['type'] == "access":
        return secret
    else:
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=jwt_payload["sub"]).one()
        return secret + user.hashed_password

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username='example').one()
    access_token = create_access_token({'user': user, 'token_type': 'access'})
    refresh_token = create_access_token({'user': user, 'token_type': 'refresh'})
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token)
```

You could also use the `Flask.g` object to to store what type of token you are making in a global variable, but I think that would probably be worse then the above solution.

Comment: I had to interchange jwt_headers and jwt_payload in the arguments of the decode_key_loader which seems odd because according to the latest docs the arguments you have passed are in the correct order, however I am using version 3.25.0 so maybe that is what caused the error. Thankyou for your answer :) .

Comment: Yep, that argument order was a change in the 4.0.0 release to keep everything consistent in your callback function. :+1: